# What is the best way to compare two possible set of values of the same object in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

Let me elaborate on the ask. I have a set of objects say, A, B, C etc. and I have a set of scenarios say, case1, case2 and case3 etc. based on which the values of the objects can change. What is the best approach to find the scenario which gives the optimum value for the object?

My approach at present is as follows:

- Implement the conditions for Case1 and store the values of the objects in a Map<object, ArrayList>
- Implement the conditions for Case2 and store the values of the objects in a second Map<object, ArrayList> etc.
- Then compare the list of values in each map

[Edited]: To add more clarity on the problem statement and simplify with an example.
Say, I have an employee class which stores the weekly salary and the cost of each employee. I add a certain weightage to salary and the cost parameters such that the weightage sums up to a 100.  I want to find out what is the optimum value of allowance that would give the best objective, that is, the best balance between salary and cost.

```
 public class Employee(){
   private String employeeId;
   private double[] weeklySalary;
   private double[] weeklyCost;
 }

 public class App{
    public static void main(){
      
      Set<Employee> employees = {...say, A, B, C etc.}

      double minAllowance = 10;
      double maxAllowance = 30;
      double stepSize = 5;
      while(minAllowance <= maxAllowance){
          for(Employees e: setOfEmployees){
               double[] salary = e.getWeeklySalary();
               double[] cost = e.getWeeklyCost();
               double allowance = ... code to compute allowance et al
               //if map1 is empty place in map1
               map1.put(e, ArrayList<Double> newCost);
               //if map2 is empty etc put in map2
          }
          minAllowance += stepSize;

      }
       //finally check all the maps created above for the best allowance value 
    }

 }


  Case1:
   ArrayList<Double> array1 = {1,2,3};
   ArrayList<Doubel> array2 = {3,4,5};
   myMatrix1.put('A',array1)
   myMatrix1.put('B',array2);
   totMatrix.put(myMatrix1,18); //sum of all elements in the two lists

  Case2:
  ArrayList<Double> array3 = {9,10,11};
  ArrayList<Double> array4 = {12,10,1};
  myMatrix2.put('A',array3);
  myMatrix2.put('B',array4);
  totMatrix.put(myMatrix2,53);
```

Then I need to sum up the values of the two arraylists in the two matrices and find the one that gives the highest value. For instance, case2 in the above example gives the best value for my set of objects.

Now the challenge is that as the number of scenarios increase, I would end up creating a number of such maps which I think must be avoided. How best to achieve this?

Would be grateful for any directions on the same! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The question does not provide any info about the classes you are using. I had to guess how the classes should look like.

Here are two approaches. The first one uses custom classes `Item` and `Scenario` which is my best guess on how your actual classes look like. The second approach uses `Map`s.

**Option 1:**

Using custom classes:

```
public class Item {
    
    private final char id;
    
    private final double[] values;
    
    public Item(char id, double... values) {
        this.id = id;
        this.values = values;
    }
    
    public final char getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    public final double[] getValues() {
        return values;
    }
    
    public final double getTotalValue() {
        return Arrays.stream(values).sum();
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[id=" + id + ", values=" + Arrays.toString(values) + "]";
    }
    
}

public class Scenario {
    
    private final Item[] items;
    
    public Scenario(Item... items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
    
    public final Item[] getItems() {
        return items;
    }
    
    public final double getTotalValue() {
        return Arrays.stream(items).mapToDouble(Item::getTotalValue).sum();
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Arrays.toString(items);
    }
    
}
    
public static final Scenario getHighestScenario(Scenario... scenarios) {
    return Arrays.stream(scenarios)
            .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(Scenario::getTotalValue).reversed())
            .findFirst().orElse(null);
}
```

Then:

```
Scenario case1 = new Scenario(new Item('A', 1, 2, 3), new Item('B', 3, 4, 5));
Scenario case2 = new Scenario(new Item('A', 9, 10, 11), new Item('B', 12, 10, 1));
 
System.out.println("Total values: [case1=" + case1.getTotalValue()
        + ", case2=" + case2.getTotalValue() + "]");
System.out.println("Highest values: " + getHighestScenario(case1, case2));
```

Output:

```
Total values: [case1=18.0, case2=53.0]
Highest values: [[id=A, values=[9.0, 10.0, 11.0]], [id=B, values=[12.0, 10.0, 1.0]]]
```

**Option 2:**

In case you prefer to use `Map` you can use `stream`:

```
public static Map<Character, List<Double>> highestValues(Map<Character, List<Double>>... matrices) {
    return Arrays.stream(matrices).collect(
            Collectors.toMap(matrix -> sumValues(matrix), 
                    Function.identity(), (m1, m2) -> m1,  TreeMap::new))
            .lastEntry().getValue();
}

public static double sumValues(Map<?, List<Double>> matrix) {
    return matrix.values().stream().flatMap(List::stream)
                    .mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).sum();
}
```

Then:

```
Map<Character, List<Double>> matrix1 = Map.of(
            'A', List.of(1d, 2d, 3d),
            'B', List.of(3d, 4d, 5d));
Map<Character, List<Double>> matrix2 = Map.of(
            'A', List.of(9d, 10d, 11d),
            'B', List.of(12d, 10d, 1d));
    
System.out.println("Total values: [matrix1=" + sumValues(matrix1) 
            + ", matrix2=" + sumValues(matrix1) + "]");
    
System.out.println("Highest values: " + highestValues(matrix1, matrix2));
```

Output:

```
Total values: [matrix1=18.0, matrix2=53.0]
Highest values: {A=[9.0, 10.0, 11.0], B=[12.0, 10.0, 1.0]}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Oboe but I would still end up creating multiple matrices which I want to avoid.

Comment: Can you post the class of the objects A, B, C...? In the question, the scenarios are represented by a `char` and the values by an `ArrayList<Double>`. If you give more details on the type of objects I can adapt the answer to your specific case.

Comment: I added some more details, hope it helps to clarify what I am trying to achieve without creating a number of maps for each iteration. Thank you!